# Curl error 7 on vagrant using guzzle

Tags: php, curl, vagrant, box, guzzle

I've get an `Curl error 7: Failed to connect to site1.local port 8000: Connection refused`, when i call it from another local site (site2.local). Both sites run on the same Vagrant box.

When i replace the url to an url of an external site (eg. google.com), there is no problem in connecting.

Why does vagrant refuse a call from his own? 
I searched the problem, but couldn't find any solution to this.

Is there a way to call to another site on the same server using curl?

edit:

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(path + '/Homestead.yaml')))
end
```

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: C:/Users/Robert/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/Robert/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: A:/homestead/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: site1.local
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/work/work-site-1/public
   - map: site2.local
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/work/work-site-2/public
```

Comment: edited question with vagrantfile and homestead.yaml

Answer (score 2):

The `8000` and `8443` ports are only used when you want to access a site in vagrant from your local box (host machine). If you want to access a site within vagrant (guest machine) you should use the standard HTTP port (`80`), since no kind of mapping is needed.

I bet that's the issue.