# How to use php cURL on local vagrant?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, vagrant, homestead

I have the following piece of code which works on my remote server

```
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/social/api/auth/login_or_register",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($credentials)
    ));
$exec = curl_exec($myCurl);
```

I decided to port the project to local for further development so I have set up a vagrant virtual machine with everything needs, everything seems to work normally except the piece of code above which gives me the following error:

> Curl failed with error #7: Failed to connect to project.dev port 8000: Connection refused

Any hints on how I can work around this problem so that I can develop normally on local ?

Comment: Is it not because Vagrant is forwarding port 80 (local to the machine) to appear as port 8000 (to your VM host)? You could confirm this by visiting the URL of the site while on the guest machine (e.g. `curl localhost` from the terminal after `vagrant ssh`)

Comment: Thank you gpmcadam. Your answer solved my problem. I replaced {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']} with project.dev and everything worked as expected

Comment: just use the default port 80 [answered link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879837/2636545)

Answer (score 8):

add in /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 project.dev

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That I already have on my Windows machine, or should I do that on the Virtual Machine after SSHing into it ?

Comment: on the Virtual Machine